# AWS SSO session duration

Tags: amazon-web-services

I recently created accounts in AWS Organizations using Control Tower, and assigned SSO users to access them. Currently the SSO session duration is set to 12 hours, the max I could get. My manager is telling me that he needs the flexibility of having more that 12 hours for a session duration, specially for production account/user. So far my search around the Internet has not provided me the result I am looking for. So, I have decided to write this post to see if people with the same experience had found solutions for themselves and willing to share. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That kind of limitation will exist even if you used an external SSO provider. I've worked places with it set to one hour, and that was a major pain, but is really that big of deal to have to sign in again every 12 hours? that's a lot longer than the average work day.

Comment: Also, it's odd to say "especially" for production, which generally has higher security requirements that non-prod.

Answer (score 0):

I'm siding with AWS on this: SSO into your AWS account should be as short as possible. SSO is for real humans doing real administrative work (using their keyboards, mouse, etc.). If your manager works more than 12hours a day managing the console (very unlikely), then they will need to login again after 12 hours.

The only real answer is that your manager needs training, and should be told "no" on their request. Because:

- is is unlikely that your manager spends more than 12hours straight managing the AWS console (that would be a smell in itself:

  - they're not much of a manager if they truly spend 12h nonstop in front of a console,
  - they need to automate things a little more, "fat fingering" things 12h per day, that doesn't sound very "5 pillars of aws" to me,
- nobody should spend 12h a day in front of the AWS console. With CI/CD pipelines, and infrastructure as code, all requests should be rather short,
- when you go out for lunch, or leave for the night, it's rather insecure to have that command line still able to talk to systems, especially to PROD systems (PROD SSO sessions should be even shorter than any test systems).

When people come in, in the morning, they login to their org. From there, using SSO, they can go to the AWS console. That's not too much to ask. Of course, they could always create an IAM User, and assign a key to it. But then they need to rotate their passwords and keys (AWS SSO's point is exactly to avoid all these hassles).

I think your manager is misunderstanding what SSO is used for. I think they think that they need their SSO session open while some processes take place? In reality, whatever they want to have running for 12h or more should run on AWS without them being connected to the AWS console. If they designed something that requires them to be constantly connected, that's a smell too. They should use VPN-peering, or whatever else to do system-to-system communication if they have some things running on premise and others in the AWS cloud (not use AWS SSO to keep a connection path open).

So, short answer, ask the manager why they need sessions that last more than 12hours. Their answer is probably going to either detect a misunderstanding from them (their request will go "poof"), or, there might be the added benefit that you will find some design flaw in how things are setup currently.

Answer (score 0):

12 hours is the absolutely max that AWS allows for SSO session duration.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/howtosessionduration.html

in my experience, we originally set it to 1 hour, but recently up it to 4 hours. Can't image someone need to retain a SSO session for longer than 4 to 8 hours.